# finding angle of rotation from origin to a vector in 3d space threejs

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, three.js, 3d

i have a vector in a three dimensional space.

is there any way to get the angle of rotation from the origin to this vector on each axis.

that is if the vector is on x=6,y=-10,z=20

from the origin x=0, y=0, z=0 on axis x,y and z on what angle the vector is.

trying to figure this out from sometime now in threejs.
any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle of 2 vectors can be found with this formula : `v1•v2 = |v1||v2| cos(angle)`
To find the angle, you need to `acos` the dot product of your 2 vectors.

According to the documentation, in ThreeJS you can find the dot product like that :
`dotproductV1V2 = V1.dot(V2)`

Then `acos` the result to find the angle : `Math.acos(dotproductV1V2)`

**Edit :**

Example to get angle of each component of the vector :

```
var V1x = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)
var V1y = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)
var V1z = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)

var V2 = new THREE.Vector3(6, -10, 20)

var V2xz = new THREE.Vector3(V2.x, 0, V2.z)
var V2xy = new THREE.Vector3(V2.x, V2.y, 0)

//angle in radian between origin X axis and X axis of V2
var angle_V1V2x = Math.acos(V1x.dot(V2xz.normalize()))

//angle in radian between origin Y axis and Y axis of V2
var angle_V1V2y = Math.acos(V1y.dot(V2xy.normalize()))

//angle in radian between origin Z axis and Z axis of V2
var angle_V1V2z = Math.acos(V1z.dot(V2xz.normalize()))
```

Comment: thank you so much , will this give.. rotation angle on each axis  from origin ?? i want to get the angle from each axis to this point.

Comment: No you will get the angle between your 2 vectors in 3D space. If you want angle rotation on each axis from origin, project your vector on planes : e.g. `V2.y = 0` to project on XZ plane and calculate with X axis : `V1=(1, 0, 0)` This will give you the angle on X axis. Do the same with Z axis (0, 0, 1) and finally project your vector on another plane : e.g. XY doing `V2.z = 0`and calculate with `V1=(0, 1, 0)`

Comment: it will be helpful if you can give me a sample code. i am very new to this and almot lost

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample of what i explained you in my previous comment. Hope this works and helps you ;)

Comment: this is awesome.. thank you so much.. only one problem is the dot product is always bigger than 1 so it return NAN always

Comment: I forgot to inlude something I wrote at the begining of my answer. The dot need to be calculated on normalized vectors. I edit my answer with this modification. Also the angle you get is in radian to you need to convert it to degrees if you want ;)